# I cannot minimize my footer using jquery animate

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I have a fixed footer where i want it to minimise when clicked on an icon

this is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Qy6Sj/693/

```
#window{
width:400px;
border:solid 1px;
}

#title_bar{
background: #FEFEFE;
height: 25px;
width: 100%;
}
#button{
border:solid 1px;
width: 25px;
height: 23px;
float:right;
cursor:pointer;
}
#box{
height: 250px;
background: #DFDFDF;
}
.bar{margin-top:50px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you have placed the toggle function inside the click, so it was not working properly, place the toggle function outside the click and it works fine, but change the + to - sign

```
    $("#button").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");
    }
});

    $("#button").toggle(
  function() {
    $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: "50px" }, 500)
  },
  function() {
    $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 500);
  }
);
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qy6Sj/699/)

Or You could do it this way

```
$("#button").click(function(){
if($(this).html() == "-"){
    $(this).html("+");
        $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 500)
}
else{
    $(this).html("-");
        $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: "50px" }, 500);
}


});
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qy6Sj/697/)

Comment: good answer but more info to explain it what OP is done wrong. Its a suggestion just do not put only piece of code.

Comment: actually i forgot to tell you that my footer is absolute position with height of 100px. How I i give it bottom=-100px

Answer (score 2):

Please try this way

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var _self = $(this);
    if(_self.hasClass('active')){

        $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 500,function(){
            _self.html("+");      
            _self.removeClass('active');  
        });
    }
    else{

        $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: "50px" }, 500,function(){
            _self.addClass('active');            
            _self.html("-");
        });
    }

});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vsok/yXP9y/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#button").on("click", function(){
if($(this).html() == "-"){
    $(this).html("+");
    $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 500)
}
else{
    $(this).html("-");
    $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: "50px" }, 500)
}
});
```

This works.

The reason the click and toggle combination didn't work was because toggle itself is a click based event. So you were effectively doubling the click event and causing it to stack.

Answer (score 0):

**Toggle** is also **using a click action and animation** so you don't need to use it twice! You were very close to the solution :-). You could also only use toggle if you wanted to.

This will do what you want!

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");
        $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: "50px" }, 500)
    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");
         $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 500);
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript to this :

```
    $("#button").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");

        $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: "50px" }, 500)

    }
    else{
        $(this).html("-");

    $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 500);

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for instead:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgKWH/)

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    if($(this).html() == "-"){
        $(this).html("+");
        $("#box").animate({ height: "0px" }, 500);
    } else {
        $(this).html("-");
        $("#box").animate({ height: "250px" }, 500);
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $("#button").on('click',function(){
        var html= ($(this).html() == "-") ? '+' : '-';
        var mr= ($('#title_bar').css('marginTop') == "0px") ? '50px' : '0px';
        $(this).html(html);
        $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: mr }, 500)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a very Simple try this **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/DS66b/)**

```
$("#button").click(function(){
if($(this).html() == "-"){
    $(this).html("+");
        $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: "0px" }, 500)
}
else{
    $(this).html("-");
        $("#title_bar").animate({ marginTop: "50px" }, 500);
}


});
```